# Add a datepicker for each of the input element in the last cell of a HTML table

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have an HTML table with multiple rows and the element in the last cell is an input type="text". How can I add the datepicker for all the inputs in the last cell of my HTML table?

Comment: Why can you add a simple class to your input element in last cell and use that? However you can use `$("table").find("tr td:last :text").datepicker();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("table").find("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("td :last").datepicker();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6SZn7/)**

Comment: Appears to be useful. But I am trying to find the input element inside the td like below:





<table>
<tr>
  <td>TDLabel1</td>
  <td><input type="text" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>TDLabel2</td>
  <td><input type="text" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>TDLabel3</td>
  <td><input type="text" value=""/></td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: Give it a class and address use that class as a selector?

Comment: I end up doing this. The above solution (td: last) is not working for some reason.

var d0DateInput = $(this).find("td :last").find("input");
d0DateInput.datepicker();

Comment: It's working with the above change now. Many thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/

Use following jquery datepicker plugin

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table input[type=text]').Zebra_DatePicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class let's say `.datepicker` to each of your target elements to avoid complex css selectors. Then you include your datepicker [sources](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and instanciate a new datepicker for each element.

```
<input class="datepicker" type="text">

jQuery('.datepicker').each(function() {
    var toBeTransformedIntoDatepicker = jQuery(this);
    toBeTransfomedIntoDatepicker.datepicker();
});
```

Or simply, like satpal recommended, write:

```
jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Comment: Why not simple `jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker()`? You don't need `each`.

Comment: Your right. However, an advantage of using `each` is that you could set different options for each element instead of one global option. But that is clearly not needed in this case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

IN order to put datepicker to all last cell of HTML table, you need to loop through the last item like as follows

```
$('[input[name=lastelementname]').each( function ( i , val ) {
    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" });

});
```